# Ember.js - how to bind an object value with property of a controller

Tags: object, ember.js, binding, controller, observers

Ember.js newbie question:

What is the best way (if it is possible), to bind an object value with property of a controller ?

Assuming, we have this bit of code:

```
App.Stalker = Ember.Mixin.create({
  init: function() {
    this._super();
    var props = this.get('watchProperties');
    Ember.assert("watchProperties should be an array", Ember.isArray(props));
    props.forEach(function(property) {
      Ember.addObserver(this, property, this, '%@Changed'.fmt(property));
    }, this);
  },

  willDestroy: function() {
    this._super();
    this.get('watchProperties').forEach(function(property) {
      Ember.removeObserver(this, property, this, '%@Changed'.fmt(property));
    }, this);
  }
});

App.states = Ember.Object.createWithMixins(App.Stalker, {
  watchProperties: 'state'.w(),
  stateChanged: function() {
    console.log("idle changed");
  }
});

App.IndexController= Ember.Controller.extend({
  state: *// How do I bind with App.states.state*,
  contentDidChange: function() {
    console.log('idle !!!');
    this.transitionToRoute("idle");
  }.observes('state')
    });

// Here is use a jQuery plugin to check if the User of the app goes in the idle mode

App.IndexView = Ember.View.extend({
  didInsertElement : function(){
    self = this;
    this._super();
    $( document ).on( "idle.idleTimer", function(event, elem, obj){
        App.states.set('state', 'idle');
        console.log(self.get("controller.state"));
        });
  }
});
```

Comment: try replacing the line "state: *// How do I bind with App.states.state*" with stateBinding: "App.states.state"

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. If I use "App.states.state" it will give me "undefined". I updated the code, so you can have a better preview of what I am trying to achieve. Thank you !

Comment: @fanta was right. All you need is `stateBinding: "App.states.state"`. [Example](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/huwegidu/2/edit) (Replaced timeout with click event, for testing). Now whether this will be usable to achieve what you want is another matter.

Comment: Thank you @panta82, all clear now. What I want to achieve, is to create an app where I check if a user is idle, if so I want to redirect him to an idle template and if he is active again, I want to redirect him to the index template. I have a sample here: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/qudip/1/edit, and it works, but the problem is that it doesn't go on and on, I receive an error. Many thanks for your help !

Comment: I didn't check the whole code, but change the lines where you're setting states in lazy controller and index controller, you have this.set(this.state, "idle"); it should be this.set('state', 'idle'), and this.set('state', 'active');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get your example working... sort of.

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  actions: {
    lazyState: function (state) {
      console.log("lazyState: " + state);
      switch (state) {
        case "idle":
          this.transitionTo("lazy");
          break;
        case "active":
          this.transitionTo("index");
          break;
        default: throw new Error("Invalid state");
      }
    }
  }
});

App.LazyView = Ember.View.extend({
  _handler: null,
  didInsertElement : function(){
    console.log("insert lazy");
    var self = this;
    this._super();
    var handler = function (event, elem, obj) {
      Ember.run(function () {
        self.get("controller").send("lazyState", "active");
      });
    };
    $(document).on("active.idleTimer", handler);
    this.set("_handler", handler);
  },
  willDestroyElement: function() {
    $(document).off("active.idleTimer", this.get("_handler"));
    this.set("_handler", null);
  }
});

// Index Views functionality

App.IndexView = Ember.View.extend({
  _handler: null,
  didInsertElement : function(){
    console.log("insert index");
    self = this;
    this._super();
    var handler = function (event, elem, obj) {
      Ember.run(function () {
        self.get("controller").send("lazyState", "idle");
      });
     };
    $(document).on("idle.idleTimer", handler);
    this.set("_handler", handler);
  },
  willDestroyElement: function () {
    $(document).off("idle.idleTimer", this.get("_handler"));
    this.set("_handler", null);
  }
});
```

[JSBin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/laxomesi/2/edit)

I whipped this into a working order, however I almost didn't post it as the answer. IMO this is neither the  most stellar implementation, nor the correct approach. To continue from here, you'd need to refactor `IndexView` implementation into some sort of `Mixin`, or move it to `ApplicationView`. Then you'd need to implement some way to save the current location when entering 'idle' mode, so you don't always go back to index...

Keep at it long enough, and I think you'll arrive to what I feel is the right solution: don't use Routes and Views at all.

From your description, all you need is to show some kind of screen-saver while user is idle. You don't need to switch routes for that. There is no user interaction to be had on the idle screen. Instead, just render whatever DOM you want for idle screen into a hidden div in the main layout, and use jQuery to show/hide it while user is idle. Or put it into a `#if isIdle` block and change `isIdle` from a global event handler.